# Parse Query saving multiple objects

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

Currently trying to save objects to parse database, when i println the objects they contain the new array that i wanted inside the array field but for some reason it won't save to table been on this a while any ideas?

The array needs to add a new integer value for each one corresponding to each the queries,the "test" array archives this but saving each object to the USER class seems to be a problem

```
func taskAllocation(){
//        var query = PFQuery(className: "Tasks")
        var query = PFUser.query()
//        let user = PFUser()
        var posts:[PFUser] = []
        query.whereKey("Year", equalTo: yearTextField.text.toInt())
        query.whereKey("Class", equalTo: classTextField.text.toInt())
        query.whereKey("Keystage", equalTo: keystageTextField.text.toInt())
//        query.limit = 10

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        } else {
            if objects.isEmpty {
                println("empty query")
            } 
            else {

                for object in objects as [PFUser]  {

                    var test:[Int] = object["taskIDs"] as [Int]

                    test.append(self.getIndex)
                    println(test)

                object.setValue(test, forKey: "taskIDs")
                object["tasksCorrect"] = "hello"
                posts.append(object)



                }
                println(posts)
                PFUser.saveAllInBackground(posts)


            }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to save these components to your "Tasks" class and not your User class. PFUser Query is just for the "_User" class which does not have the tasks in it.

```
            var tasks:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Tasks")
            // Make sure in your parse data table you have the columns  created as type String or Int 
            item["Year"] = yearTextField.text.toInt()
            item["Keystage"] =  keystageTextField.text.toInt()
            item["Class"] =     classTextField.text.toInt())
            // Save the task to a user, make sure you create a Username column in your data table
            item["Username"] = PFUser.currentUser().username

            // save it 
            item.saveInBackgroundWithTarget(nil , selector: nil)
```

Your code is a little clunky so I made assumptions on what your trying to do. It might be beneficial taking a screen shot of your task class.

Comment: Ahh, not quite, sorry i've edited my posts just to make sure there is less ambiguity. But adding single values outside a for loop is fine. I need to update every object in the user table that corresponds to the query. post seems to contain the correct objects, but nothing seems to save it.